# Span of sine and cosine equals span of positive and negative complex exponentials proof

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I need to prove that 
$$
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\span}{\text{span}_\C}
\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}=\span\{e^{ikx}, e^{-ikx}\}
$$
This is my proof but I am not 100 % sure it's correct, mainly because I'm not sure I can just define the span of sine and cosine like I do..

**My Proof**

Using the fact that
$$
e^{ikx}=\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx) \quad \text{and} \quad e^{-ikx}=\cos(kx)-i\sin(kx)
$$
We can write sine and cosine as follows
$$
\cos(kx)=\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(kx)=\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}
$$
And then we can rewrite the span of cosine and sine using the definition (is this even correct?)
$$
\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}=\{a\cos(kx)+b\sin(kx): k\in\mathbb{Z}, a,b\in\C\}
$$
And then substituting the formulas found above and doing some manipulations
$$
\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}=\{\left(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2i}\right)e^{ikx} + \left(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2i}\right)e^{-ikx}: k\in\mathbb{Z}, a,b\in\C\}
$$
but now we can rewrite
$$
a':=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2i} \quad \text{and} \quad b':=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2i}
$$
and notice that $a', b'\in\C$. Therefore we obtain that 
$$
\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}=\{a'e^{ikx}+b'e^{-ikx}: k\in\mathbb{Z},a',b'\in\C\}=:\span\{e^{ikx}, e^{-ikx}\}
$$

Is this correct? I'm not sure this argument works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is basically correct though, perhaps, too cumbersome. I'd go as follows:$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\span}{\text{span}_\C}$

$$
\begin{cases}\cos(kx)=\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2} \\{}\\ \sin(kx)=\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}\end{cases}\;\;\implies
\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}\subset\span\{e^{ikx}, e^{-ikx}\}
$$

and on the other hand:

$$e^{\pm ikx}=\cos kx\pm i\sin kx\implies\span\{\cos(kx), \sin(kx)\}\supset\span\{e^{ikx}, e^{-ikx}\}$$

You can remark that all the involved coefficients are complex ones, too...

Comment: I like how you use the definition of a subset in your proof, it's really nice!